# Will entityManager.createQuery().executeUpdate() execute immediately on DB?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm using hibernate jpa. I'm trying to execute an update query and want to tell if the update actually happen or not based on the return value because I may have multiple processes doing the same updates and I only want to continue with the process that successfully update the record. (Relying on mysql return 1 iff the update happen successfully, 0 if nothing changed.)

```
int update = entityManager.createQuery("update Employee set name = \'xxxx\' where id=1").executeUpdate();
```

My question is that with default flush mode (`AUTO`), will this query being executed on the db? (if not, does the return value still make sense?) What about flush mode = `COMMIT`? Do I need to do entityManager.flush()? (I feel like the query execution will bypass the entityManager so flush doesn't do anything?)

What if I use JPA repository instead of the native query?

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Employee SET name = :name WHERE id = :id)
int update(long id, String name)
```

Will the return value reflects the rows changed in DB or just the persistent context?

Comment: Yes, it will. How could it return the number of updated or deleted entities if it didn't? Why would the javadoc say "Execute an update or delete statement." if it didn't do that?

Comment: @JBNizet Does it write to database immediately or varies time to time.

Comment: Again, how could the database tell the method how many rows were updated if the query is not sent to the database?

Comment: @JBNizet thanks! I've update the question- I'm also curious about the behavior of using JPA repository, can you help take a look?